# Is "Chromepass" by Nirsoft legit?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

XP
Chrome

I need to find out a password in the Chrome browser and I have found "Chromepass" by Nirsoft.

Is this a legitimate facility?

Comment: When I ran it, it found no passwords. ???

Comment: Perhaps you need to run it as **admin**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Nirsoft is a legitimate company that provides the "[Chromepass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html)" utility and many other great software utilities for free. They don't employ viruses or any other type of malicious code.

I don't have any connection or relationship with Nirsoft. I only use and like many of their utilities.

Comment: Seconded. Nirsoft utilities have been a great help to me both personally and professionally.

Comment: Nirsoft has saved my butt many times:) I think my fav tool of theirs is the one that lets you edit autocomplete history for Outlook.

Answer (score 4):

Nirsoft is OK.
But be careful to download really from their website.
There are Trojans around that masquerade as Chromepass, so don't pull the file from any random download site...

Comment: A good suggestion for most software in fact.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Nir Sofer tools for a long time..

They are small (not bloated) and powerful utilities, in the site you will find more tools to hack into security features of several applications... needless to say you can only use them if you a logged in as a legitimate user... or a machine administrator.